# Can I use Radix themes in Shadcn?

Tags: radix

I'm using Shadcn UI which is based on Radix. I noticed now that Radix offers nice themes as opposed to Shadcn. Can I somehow integrate Radix theme with Shadcn UI library?

Comment: Hi. Were you able to add Radix theme with shadcnui? Some components from radix ui are missing in shadcn

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can as long as your shadcn/ui color CSS variables don't clash with Radix UI Theme.